# PieChart with Multiple Measures

Tags: einstein-analytics, einstein, crm-analytics, tableau-crm

I want to display a piechart based on multiple measures . For ex , Total Revenue will be overall piechart segment length. Total Profit , Total Loss , Total discounts etc will be multiple segments in piechart.

However i do not see the option of creating piechart or doughnut based on multiple measures / number fields in CRM Analytics. This seems to be possible in Tableau desktop but not in EA/CRM Analytics.

Anyone faced similar situation? Any suggestions or workaround please ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to switch to query mode and manipulate the data to get the output you desire. In the chart widget, you can set the **Center Value** property to "Total"

q = load "opportunities";

q = group q by all;

r = foreach q generate sum('Total Profit') as 'Measure', "Total Profit" as 'Label';

s = foreach q generate sum('Total Loss') as 'Measure', "Total Loss" as 'Label';

t = foreach q generate sum('Total discounts') as 'Measure', "Total discounts" as 'Label';

result = union r, s, t;